# How to create "tags" for my post model in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Finally I have configured and have been trying to use the google for finding this, but was unable to.  So, I tried something myself, but not sure is it correct....

I have Post model, which is having title, message, category, and finally tags.

Front end side, user has to fill out a form with title, message.  From a drop down, she or he is entering the category.

Finally, I have made a different collection with a one dozen tags for test, such as "computer","mac","windows","linux","hardware",etc.

Right now only I have a text input for the tag, and there is no validations or something like on the stackoverflow where type in "javascript" and it brings up a result called "javascript, 100000 questions".  But, user enters the tags using semi colon separator and the values are added to tags field in the Post model.  Forgot to mention, only validation is to make sure the texts entered in the tag are existing in the tags collection.

So it will be having something like:

`"title" : "a post", "message" : "something", "category" : "computer", "tags": "linux;computer;"`

How can I to make this better?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"tags"` should be an array.
So you separate values from the input and push them to post's tags.

Comment: Thank you Sir.  I have found this on the google after your solution `http://tgrall.github.io/blog/2015/04/21/mongodb-playing-with-arrays/` which I will study, and come back to here to report the result

Comment: Thank you Sir.  I have done the suggested and I have now it working :)